# Compare dates using awk in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, date

I have a file and each line has some info and a date,so what I want is to print the lines with dates after a given date. I use this awk command

```
sort -t$'|' -k5 $2 | awk -F '|' -v DatedAfter=$4 '!/^#/ && $5>=DatedAfter {print $0}'
```

Where $4 is a date in DD/MM/YYYY format given and $2 is the file I use in the format bellow.

```
1099511628908|Chen|Wei|female|02/08/1989|2010-05-24T20:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1978|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
```

So when i execute my code i get these results.

```
./tool.sh --born-since 17/11/1983 -f events.dat
1099511629352|Nunez|Jorge|female|17/11/1986|2011-04-04T05:54:52.693+0000|201.221.59.59|Opera|Facebook
1099511638548|Phan|Don|female|17/5/1981|2011-04-19T00:14:15.041+0000|112.72.79.36|Opera|Flickr
1099511638387|Znaimer|Moses|male|17/8/1980|2011-05-12T01:03:01.291+0000|94.199.19.90|Internet Explorer|Youtube
6597069776449|Svensson|Ernst|male|30/11/1981|2012-04-22T05:16:03.557+0000|31.31.166.207|Opera|Youtube
2199023258994|Ngoche|Alex Obanda|female|30/9/1987|2011-07-22T16:36:27.420+0000|41.81.41.21|Opera|Google+
7696581405294|Dobrunov|Aleksandr|male|31/12/1989|2012-05-15T05:46:31.439+0000|31.25.243.122|Internet Explorer|LinkedIn
2199023266450|Charoenpura|Somchai|male|4/12/1987|2011-08-30T20:34:41.524+0000|110.76.154.132|Mozilla|Youtube
3298534890514|Chen|Hsin|male|4/4/1988|2011-11-03T16:32:44.238+0000|115.42.116.30|Safari|Google+
2199023261081|Ben Dhifallah|Karim|male|6/4/1980|2011-06-11T02:24:17.194+0000|193.95.74.75|Chrome|Twitter
8796093024550|Yang|Lei|male|7/1/1990|2012-07-15T17:14:42.186+0000|1.4.92.176|Mozilla|Facebook
```

Comment: I assume (please confirm) that the first line of code in your question is part of a script which expects a filename as the 2nd parameter and a date (in the format of DD-MM-YYYY?) as the 4th parameter?

Comment: Not exactly, the command i use is like this
./exec.sh  -f <file> --born-since <DD/MM/YYYY>.

Comment: Please edit that incoming date format into the question, so answerers knows how to compare it. Thank you!

Comment: May I doubt that it works with the first date format either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be easier if the dates are in `YYYYMMDD` (then they will be in lexicographic and numeric order). You can use `gensub` for that in awk. For example:

```
awk -F"|" -v d="$d" -v dp='(..)/(..)/(....)' 'BEGIN {gensub(dp, "\3\2\1", d)} {dt=$5; gensub(dp, "\3\2\1", dt);} dt >= d' foo
```

The `d` variable holds the date for comparison, and `dp` holds the pattern matching a `DD/MM/YYYY` date. Then with `gensub`, we move around those (`\3`, `\2`, `\1` being the matched groups (`(....)`, the second `(..)`, the first `(..)`, respectively). Same with the fifth field of each line, which we copy to avoid modifying the input.

I expanded your example input with some more dates:

```
1099511628908|Chen|Wei|female|02/08/1989|2010-05-24T20:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1978|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1979|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1977|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1980|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/03/1978|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
```

And got this result using `19/04/1978` for comparison:

```
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1978|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1979|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|19/04/1980|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DT="01/08/1989"
awk -F\| -vDT=${DT:6}${DT:3:2}${DT:0:2} 'substr($5, 7) substr($5, 4, 2) substr($5, 1, 2) > DT' file
1099511628908|Chen|Wei|female|02/08/1989|2010-05-24T20:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
```